# Searching in databound comboBox?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, combobox

Guys I have a comboBox that is configured to work like dropdownlist. It is being populated through database. It is working flawlessly.

Now what I want to do is is this :
For example I have comboBox that is getting "Names" column from database table "tblPersons" and displaying it.
if, For example, there are total of 4 entries in database table "tblPersons"

1. Ali Khan
2. Ahmed Khan
3. Bilal Khan
4. Bilal Farooqi

So when I write "Ahmed Farooqi" in comboBox (comboBox should be editable and it should display all entries with name "Ahmed" once I have written "Ahmed") and press enter, it should search in database table "tblPersons" - if "Ahmed Farooqi" is found - it should select it, if "Ahmed Farooqi" is not found - it should ask if I want to create new entry in database table "tblPersons", if I click "yes" it should open another form for adding new person and if I click "No" it should do nothing.

How should I do this. I am new to C#, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if my question was unclear.

Regards.

Edit : This is my test form, here I a textBox that will be used to enter Name, the textbox should search for a name in database, then if name is found, display number and email from database in their respective textboxes. If not found, it should display messagebox asking user to create a new person and if clicked yes, switch to another form (where user will create new person).

[image]

Comment: What you have done so far? Look for autocomplete properties and key up ,key down events

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also, do not include IDE tag (Visual Studio) among tags if your question is not directly about it and you just write code in it. Problems with code are seldom connected to a code editor.

Comment: I am really sorry about that, it wont happen again.

Answer (score 0):

call the fillCombo function in your form load and assign the cmb_SelectedValueChanged event to your combobox. Don't forget to set autocompletemode property to combobox.

```
cmb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend


private void fillCombo()
{
    string sql = "SELECT ID, NAME, Number, Email FROM tblPerson";
    SqlConnection Cnn = new SqlConnection("connections string");
    Cnn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Cnn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    cmb.ValueMember = "ID";
    cmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmb.DataSource = dt;    
}

private void cmb_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmb.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        txtNumber.Text = ((DataRow)cmb.SelectedItem)["Number"].ToString();
        txtEmail.Text = ((DataRow)cmb.SelectedItem)["Email"].ToString();
    }
}

private void cmb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmb.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        If (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to create a new person?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            frmNewPerson person = new frmNewPerson();
            person.Name = cmb.Text;
            if (person.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                fillCombo();
                DataRow dr = ((DataTable)cmb.DataSource).Select("Name='" + person.Name + "'")[0];
                cmb.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtNumber.Text = string.Emtpy;
            txtEmail.Text = string.Emtpy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your method. But whenever I try to run your code, it just pops up the messagebox "do you want to create new person?" without even displaying the form. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry about this. But visual studio is not installed in my computer so, i have written this code n++. So, please take my code as a logic only. it may have some bugs. I have updated my code. in this update i have created another event cmb_Validating. assign this event to your combobox.